# Скрипт на js для твича(MeddleMonkey)

Tags: javascript, twitch

Сейчас на твие есть тенденция скинов за баллы. Если с получение дополнительных балов(+50 каждые 15мин) проблем не возникло, есть расширение, то с тем как можно собственно забрать скин есть проблема.

Стримеры у которых большой онлайн сделали так что скин открывается раз в час или даже больше, я пытался забрать вручную не неполучалось, решил прибегнуть к скрипту. Написал простенький скрипт, его приложу ниже, и возникла проблема, что именно происходит я точно не знаю, но как я понял во время выполнения моего скрипта,  скрипты твич останавливаються, браузер перестает откликаться и все зависает.

Если кто-то шарит, помогите пожалуйста наживаться на стримерах с помощью технологий)

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name Twitch DENTIKcsgo glock
// @namespace MeddleMonkey Scripts
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

function sleep(ms) {
ms += new Date().getTime();
while (new Date() < ms){}
} 


sleep(1000);
document.getElementsByClassName("ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonText-sc-1qn4ixc-3 kGWcAX tw-core-button")[0].click()
sleep(3000);
document.getElementsByClassName("ScInteractableBase-awmohi-0 ScInteractableDefault-awmohi-1 bArsnw tw-block tw-border-radius-medium tw-full-width tw-interactable")[12].click()//12-элемент в предметах
sleep(5000);
document.getElementsByClassName("ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonPrimary-sc-1qn4ixc-1 jeBpig tw-core-button")[1].click()
sleep(7000);
```

Comment: Этот код планировал зациклить с помощью бесконечного цыкла, что бы можно было оставить и уйти, но с циклом я несмог даже вкладку в браузере со стримос закрыть.

Comment: Просто калацать энтер или на кнопкк мыши тоже не вариант, данные обновляються только если перезайти в предмет который хочешь забарать( это из личного наблюдения, так что не точно)

Comment: прочитайте про setTimeout, он вам здесь больше подойдет.

Comment: Сделал с setTimeout, если запустить 1 раз - все ок, если в цикл - проблема такая же.

Comment: var x = 1000;
var y = 2000;
var z = 3000;
var i = 3000;

while (1){

setTimeout(document.getElementsByClassName("ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonText-sc-1qn4ixc-3 kGWcAX tw-core-button")[0].click(), x);
x = x + i;
setTimeout(document.getElementsByClassName("ScInteractableBase-awmohi-0 ScInteractableDefault-awmohi-1 bArsnw tw-block tw-border-radius-medium tw-full-width tw-interactable")[12].click(), y);
y = y + i;
setTimeout(document.getElementsByClassName("ScCoreButton-sc-1qn4ixc-0 ScCoreButtonPrimary-sc-1qn4ixc-1 jeBpig tw-core-button")[1].click(), z);
y = y + i;
}

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1279072/edit)